# Не могу настроить Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Добрый день, никак не могу разобратся с докером, он смотрит не в ту папку.

```
webserver:
  volumes:
   - .:/app
```

При такой настройке он смотрит на путь

> C:\Users\admin\Documents\GitHub

а должен на

> C:\Users\admin\Documents\GitHub\test

Answer (score 3):

вы передаете путь текущего каталога точкой (`.`). если вы находитесь в ...\Github\, то и смотреть он туда будет. Исправьте или на `./test:/app` или перелезьте в test и запускайте оттуда

Comment: Точка обозначает не текущий каталог, а каталог с docker-compose.yml, это поведение стало таким в какой-то древней версии compose, поэтому переход ничего не даст.

Comment: я вообще хотел про это написать, но стало дико лень, подумал, автор сам поймет, когда напорется, но спасибо за дополнение